# Why does the Electric field vector curl when the current is not a steady state one?

Tags: electromagnetism

The math checks out but I was curious about knowing if we could intuitively comment on curling of the electric field when the charges start clumping/non steady-state current is present. Any hint would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.